# How to create a variable number of arguments as PGF key?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

Many interfaces use a variable number of arguments, for example in CSS

```
 margin:1pt 1pt 1pt 1pt
```

The clip functions of the graphics package also have similar examples.

Is this possible with PGF keys?

Please note that this *should not* be a comma delimited list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/test/test}{1pt 2pt 3pt 4pt}
\pgfkeysgetvalue{/test/test}{\test}
\end{document}
```

Essentially I am looking for a parser to grub a variable number of arguments and place them in individual macros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few ways...

Probably the simplest:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{%
  border/.style args={#1 #2 #3}{
    border width=#1,
    border style=#2,
    border color=#3,
  },
  border width/.store in=\borderwidth,
  border style/.store in=\borderstyle,
  border color/.store in=\bordercolor,
}



\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\tikzset{border=20pt solid blue} 
border: \borderwidth\ \borderstyle\ \bordercolor;

\tikzset{border=5pt dotted green} 
border: \borderwidth\ \borderstyle\ \bordercolor;

\tikzset{border=15pt dashed red} 
border: \borderwidth\ \borderstyle\ \bordercolor;
\end{document}
```

[image]

A bit more complicated, but allows partial specification...

```
\documentclass[varwidth, border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\empty{}
\pgfkeys{utils/.cd,
  set if not empty/.code 2 args={%
    \def\arg{#2}%
    \ifx\arg\empty%
    \else%
      \pgfkeys{#1={#2}}%
    \fi%
  }
}
\tikzset{%
  border/.style={border ..=#1 {} {} {}},
  border ../.style args={#1 #2 #3 #4}{
    /utils/set if not empty={/tikz/border width}{#1},
    /utils/set if not empty={/tikz/border style}{#2},
    /utils/set if not empty={/tikz/border color}{#3}%,
  },
  border width/.store in=\borderwidth,
  border style/.store in=\borderstyle,
  border color/.store in=\bordercolor,
}

\def\borderwidth{1pt}
\def\borderstyle{solid}
\def\bordercolor{blue}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\tikzset{border=20pt} 
border: \borderwidth\ \borderstyle\ \bordercolor;

\tikzset{border=5pt dotted} 
border: \borderwidth\ \borderstyle\ \bordercolor;

\tikzset{border=15pt dotted red} 
border: \borderwidth\ \borderstyle\ \bordercolor;
\end{document}
```

[image]

This final version is probably not exactly what is required but anyway but illustrates a general method for extracting space separated values in to separate keys...

```
\documentclass[varwidth, border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\at{@}
\pgfkeys{/utils/.cd,
  set keys/.style 2 args={
    /utils/set keys ..={{0}{#1}#2 @ @}
  },
  set keys ../.code args={#1#2#3 #4}{%
    \def\tmp{#3}%
    \ifx\tmp\at%
      \pgfkeys{#2\space n/.initial=\pgfmathresult}%
    \else%
      \pgfmathparse{int(#1+1)}%
      \pgfkeys{#2\space\pgfmathresult/.initial=#3}%      
      \pgfkeys{/utils/set keys ..={\pgfmathresult}{#2}#4}%
    \fi%
  }
}
\tikzset{
  test/.style={/utils/set keys={/tikz/test}{#1}}
}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{test={20pt 30pt 40pt 100pt}}
\pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/test n}\n
There were \n\ values
\foreach \i in {1,...,\n}{
  \par\leavevmode
  The value of `test \i' is \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/test \i}
}
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: It is close to what I am looking for, however I am not really sure how you got the result. Do you mind adding some explanatory notes? How would you handle a different case say: `border=1px solid blue` where the values are not dimensions?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides it doesn't matter whether the values are dimensions or not. I've provided a slightly different version which is a bit more relevant to your use-case.

Comment: Thanks. This is perfect. What does the `border ..=` does? I mean the `..` I don't seem to fid anuything related in the manual.

Comment: Brilliant! I see its just a string. Thanks for the help.